# Renew the chain certificate from p12 file

Tags: certificate

I have the ROOT, chain certificates, p12 key and key password. I don’t have the CA root key details.
My requirement is, I need to do renew the chain certificate by using these. Without change the signature value

Please help me on this.

Regards,
Sreenivasulu

Answer (score 1):

Without owning the CA private key, you can't renew your certificates. Even if you do have the CA key, the certificate's signature *will* change on renewal, since in practice, renewing a certificate means creating a new certificate with different expiration time. Since it is a new certificate, the signature value will be different.